# not able to do Screen navigation and back from screen

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have a 4-5 screen on my Roku channel. But I am facing a problem when I navigate from one screen to another screen.i have to work with some of my logic but I think it's not a proper way what I did. I have faced the below issue
1-Navigation from one to another screen 
2-Back from screen

I have done the navigation by doing the below procedure
1-I have declared all the screen in homescene
2-when I need to navigate I will just append that screen and show it and focus it and when I click back I will hide it.

For navigation from one to another screen

```
 m.top.AppendChild(m.ChapterDetails)
m.ChapterDetails.setFocus(true)
m.ChapterDetails.visible="true"
```

So it will navigate to ChapterDetails screen and when I click back in back I will return it false so it will come to my 1st screen of back key event and here i will just hide

```
m.ChapterDetails.setFocus(false)
m.ChapterDetails.visible="false"
```

Can you suggest me is there any way to handle this thing.

Comment: Couple of things. First, avoid using `setFocus(false)`, instead do `setFocus(true)` on the screen/element you want to focus back. Second, make sure the screen you're going back to is visible again. You could even do `m.top.removeChild(m.ChapterDetails)` to ensure the previous screen visibility is not being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Add one thing in your code :

`m.ChapterDetails.close = true`

Roku navigation first close screen is required. After the first screen is closed then the second screen will open.